# Googlemaps android setting bounds

Tags: android

Most of the examples i can find on the net use the now deprecated getMap() method.  Google says use getMapAsync().  I can draw the markers on my map however when I include the bounds code i get an IllegalStateException.  So, my question how do I properly set the LatLngBounds.Builder?

Code and LogCat follow:

```
public class TripsMap extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {
MapView mMapView;
private GoogleMap googleMap;
GoogleMapOptions options = new GoogleMapOptions();
private LatLngBounds.Builder bounds;

Trips trip;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.trips_map_fragment);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    trip = (Trips) extras.getSerializable("tripInfo");

    MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

}


@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    bounds = new LatLngBounds.Builder();

    int subTrips = trip.getSubtripsNum();

    for (int i=0; i<subTrips; i++) {
        SubTrips st = trip.getSubTrips().get(i);

        //major origin
        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(convertLatLng(st.originCoords))
                .title(st.origin));
        Log.i("MAJOR", st.origin);

        //use .include to put add each point to be included in the bounds
        bounds.include(convertLatLng(st.originCoords));


        int minor = st.intermediateStation.size();
        for (int j=0; j<minor; j++){
            IntermediateStops is = st.intermediateStation.get(j);

            //minor stop
            googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(convertLatLng(is.coords))
                    .title(is.stationName));

        }

        //major destination
        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(convertLatLng(st.destCoords))
                .title(st.destination));

        bounds.include(convertLatLng(st.destCoords));

    }

    googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds.build(), 50));

}

public LatLng convertLatLng(String s) {
    String[] latlong =  s.split(",");
    double latitude = Double.parseDouble(latlong[0]);
    double longitude = Double.parseDouble(latlong[1]);
    LatLng ll = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
    return ll;
}
```

}

Logcat:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error using newLatLngBounds(LatLngBounds, int): Map size can't be 0. Most likely, layout has not yet occured for the map view.  Either wait until layout has occurred or use newLatLngBounds(LatLngBounds, int, int, int) which allows you to specify the map's dimensions.
        at com.google.k.a.cj.b(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.c.c.a(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.c.dp.a(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.c.c.a(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.c.el.a(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.l.onTransact(SourceFile:83)
        at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:326)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.IGoogleMapDelegate$a$a.moveCamera(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.moveCamera(Unknown Source)
        at mtr.se.reskoll.TripsMap.onMapReady(TripsMap.java:87)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment$a$1.a(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.m$a.onTransact(Unknown Source)
        at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:326)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.ba.a(SourceFile:82)
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.c.er.run(Unknown Source)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
SupportMapFragment mapFragment =(SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
```

instead of

```
MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
```

The problem could also be due the reason mentioned [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/CameraUpdateFactory.html#newLatLngBounds(com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLngBounds)) in the documentation.

> Do not change the camera with this camera update until the map has
>   undergone layout (in order for this method to correctly determine the
>   appropriate bounding box and zoom level, the map must have a size).
>   Otherwise an IllegalStateException will be thrown. It is NOT
>   sufficient for the map to be available (i.e. getMap() returns a
>   non-null object); the view containing the map must have also undergone
>   layout such that its dimensions have been determined. If you cannot be
>   sure that this has occured, use newLatLngBounds(LatLngBounds, int,
>   int, int) instead and provide the dimensions of the map manually.

Comment: when I have a fragment with width and height set to match_parent and wrap_content how is one supposed to hard code that into pixels?